# The input field displays no blinking cursor or cannot typing letters in IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, cross-browser

When I clicked the input field,the blinking cursor will not display and I can't type letters.

This just happens with IE11 browser.

It works fine with Chrome, Firefox and Safari.

https://jsfiddle.net/zu1wpt1c/1/

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)">
  <input type="text" value="aaa"/>
</a>
```

If I remove "href" attribute from , it will be fine.

Why  do the "href" attributea impact input behaviour?
Is there another way to fix this issue on IE11 browser?

Comment: why do you have an `<input>` inside an `<a>` tag?

Comment: whats the purpose of a tag here?

Comment: I want to know why it's not working on  IE11 so that I will take care

Answer (score 0):

Try This, `<a href="javascript:void(0)"> aaa</a>` will give you output when you click aaa

Answer (score 0):

```html
<p>If you want to create a link</p>
<a href="javascript:void(0)">aaa</a>


<p>If you want to create a text input field</p>
<input type="text" value="aaa">
```

Comment: But it's not working on  IE11 while "<a>" element contains "<input>" element .Why?